# where to get stock price forecast

Tags: stocks, ira, retirement, price, forecasting

I am new to stock market so please be patient with me if my question does not make sense.

I have an IRA account with Fidelity. Their research tool is good and shows analysts opinion of stocks i am interested in. However, it does not provide any price forecast. For example, if i search for the stock of xyz company, it shows some of the analysts are saying "Buy" but that does not show what price range they are targeting or at what price range they think it is a good buy.

Every now and then i read in the news that abc analyst is targeting the price of a particular stock at some price so i know there are places i can go and get this information. Of course it will not be free or 100% correct but i wanted the expert opinion on what places are better to get such an information.

Any information will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Yahoo Finance offers a one year target. I've not seen any data on its accuracy/performance. Individual stock picking is not a simple matter. Those who are good at it are not giving their advice away for free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, stock prices forecasts are usually pretty subjective so in the following resources you will find differing opinions. The important thing is to read both positive and negative views and do some of your additional research and form your own opinion.

To answer your question, some analysts don't provide price targets, some just say "Buy", "Sell", "Hold", and others actually give you a price target.

Yahoo provides a good resource for collecting reports and giving you a price target.
http://screener.finance.yahoo.com/reports.html

Answer (score 4):

There's only one real list that states what people think stock prices should be, and that's the stocks order book. That lists the prices at which stock owners are willing to buy stocks now, and the price that buyers are willing to pay.

A secondary measure is the corresponding options price.

Anything else is just an opinion and not backed by money.

Comment: I do understand that its just an opinion and thats why i said "forecast" and not "guaranteed expected price" .

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for price forecasts from analysts.

Yahoo provides info in the analyst opinions section:

here is an example for [Apple](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ao?s=AAPL%20Analyst%20Opinion) the price targets are located in the "Price Target Summary" section.